# Is with-exception locking behaviour sound intentional design?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a small server script mirroring IoT traffic, and handling several kinds of packages.
In there, I have stuff in queues, and pulling from them is arranged as follows:

```
def pull_from(service, ID):
    with service.LOCK_A:
        if not ID in service.queues:
            service.queues[ID] = queue.Queue(35)
        return service.queues[ID].get(timeout=2.5)
```

Here timeout expires in for example 2.5 seconds, and then raises queues.Empty, releasing the lock. The exception is catched downstream.

Previously I have avoided stuff like this. Is this considered "sound design" or is lock release through with-exception a sort of hack that should be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s fine. [`with` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) always run `__exit__` on exceptions, by design, like a `try…finally`.